# How to request Google to add a new keyword to Google search autocorrect?

Tags: search, google-play, search-engine, google-search

Whenever I want to search for my *Android APPS* which are developed under publisher *nixaree* on the *Google search engine* or *Play Store*. Instead of displaying that *APPS* developed by *nixaree*, it displays other keyword contents and displays `did you mean: XYZ`.Is there any thing provided so that I can request *Google* to include this word as a keyword in *PlayStore* *& Web Search Engine*.

screenshot example:
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: In a nutshell, you can't

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot change anything about this because you are not the owner of the Google PlayStore; therefore, you cannot add new keywords to it. Hope this helps!